# Use of access tokens with AWS Cognito and API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm in the midst of implementing Cognito as the authorizer for my Lambda functions through API Gateway but just trying to wrap my head around a few concepts.

What is the purpose of access tokens with Cognito?

In order to authorize request I pass the id_token as the authorization header, which from my understanding you would normally pass the access token as the bearer.

The only way I see access tokens being used is if I build a custom autohrizer but since the logic is already all there there's no point.

Cheers

Comment: I have validation all working just trying to understand the use of the access_token vs the _id_token

Comment: Yep. This is not a duplicate. This is more like access toke vs id token & when to use which one

Comment: Precisely, so if someone could answer that would be great haha